# Objective-C - Interface declaration syntax

Tags: objective-c

Objective-C Syntax question. What's the "thing" inside the parenthesis mean? (`TemplateMethods` in this case?)

```
@interface CC3OpenGL (TemplateMethods)
// Methods declarations
@end
```

I see this being used a lot in Cocos3D but have no idea what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm expanding @Siriss answer,

When you want to make a category for another class, you've to write it like this. I've not idea of `Cocos3D`, so I guess `CC3OpenGL` is a class in `Cocos3D` and you want to make a category for that class and named it, `TemplateMethods`.

Lets take an example,

```
@interface UILabel (OtherMethods)
// Methods declarations
- (CGSize) getLabelSize;
@end
```

Here, we make a category of `UILabel` and named it `OtherMethods`. We can `#import` it like, `#import "UILabel+OtherMethods.h`to access methods of it.

So, now you will have a method of `UILabel` and you can access it like the same way you access to the other methods of the `UILabel`.

```
UILabel *lbl = [UILabel new];
lbl.frame = CGRectMake:(10,10,300,100);
[lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight]; //normal method
[self.view addSubview:lbl];
CGSize lblSize = [lbl getLabelSize]; //category method
```

To read more about it, [read documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) here.

Answer (score 1):

That is a category definition. Categories are a way to add methods to classes you do not own, or that you do but are domain specific. You can view the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html).